# Multiple Classes, and IndexError: list index out of range Error's

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

When i try to print an example from the class "sentence" by calling below code

```
examp3 = soup1.find_all(class_='sentence')
print(examp3[0].get_text())
```

it will give me an error like below

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/home/hudacse6/WebScrape/webscrape.py", line 33, in <module>
print(examp3[0].get_text())
IndexError: list index out of range
```

Here is the picture from web page which i want to call and print

[image: class called pic]

How to over come this error?

Here is my full html.parser Code

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

page1 = requests.get('https://www.vocabulary.com/dictionary/abet')
page2 = requests.get('https://www.thesaurus.com/browse/cite?s=t')
page3 = requests.get('https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/abet')
page4 = requests.get('https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/abet')

soup1 = BeautifulSoup(page1.content, 'html.parser')
soup2 = BeautifulSoup(page2.content, 'html.parser')
soup3 = BeautifulSoup(page3.content, 'html.parser')
soup4 = BeautifulSoup(page4.content, 'html.parser')

synonyms2 = soup1.find_all(class_='short')
synonyms3 = soup1.find_all(class_='long')
print("Short Description of ABET: ", synonyms2[0].get_text(), "\n", )
print("Brief Description of ABET: ", synonyms3[0].get_text(), "\n", )

syn = soup2.find_all('a', class_='css-18rr30y etbu2a31')
find_syn = [syns.get_text() for syns in syn]
# print(syn[0].get_text())
print("Most relevant Synonyms of ABET: ", find_syn, "\n", )

print("Examples Of ABET: ")

exmp1 = soup3.find_all(class_='eg deg')
print(exmp1[0].get_text())

examp2 = soup4.find_all(class_='mw_t_sp')
print(examp2[0].get_text())

examp3 = soup1.find_all(class_='sentence')
print(examp3[0].get_text())
```

And i had tried to call multiple same name classes at a time to print the class textes using below code but only the first class called and print. The second one is not working.

```
 #soup.findAll(True, {'class':['class1', 'class2']}) --Main Code
 examp2 = soup4.findAll(True, {'class': ['mw_t_sp', 'ex-sent first-child t no-aq sents']})
 print(examp2[1].get_text())
```

It is print only this

> Examples Of ABET:
>
> abet the commission of a crime

Here is the pic where i called this.

[image]

What,s the problem with above the code?

Comment: What if you print out the length of `examp2`?

Comment: it printed what i want.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The page https://www.vocabulary.com/dictionary/abet load the content under "Usage Examples" using javascript.

BeautifulSoup doesn't run javascript like a browser does, so the request you get don't have any `class_='sentence'` items.

"list index out of range" error, simply means there is not element [0] in the list.

You may need to parse the json response (see screenshot) or use selenium, approaches more challenging.

[image: json response]

I can help you with the json response.

The full link to get de json response according to network devTools in chrome is something like:
    https://corpus.vocabulary.com/api/1.0/examples.json?jsonp=jQuery112407918468215082872_1585769422264&query=abet&maxResults=24&startOffset=0&filter=0&_=1585769422265

We can try to make it shorter simplifying. This link seems to work fine:
https://corpus.vocabulary.com/api/1.0/examples.json?query=abet&maxResults=4

So:

```py
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import json

def parse_vocabulary_com_examples (word):

    num_of_examples = 4
    url = "https://corpus.vocabulary.com/api/1.0/examples.json?query=" + word + "&maxResults=" + str(num_of_examples)

    page = requests.get(url)
    soup = BeautifulSoup(page.content, 'html.parser')
    dictionary = json.loads(str(soup))

    for i in range (0,num_of_examples):
        print("------------------------------------------------------")
        print("name:", dictionary["result"]["sentences"][i]["volume"]["corpus"]["name"])
        print("sentence:", dictionary["result"]["sentences"][i]["sentence"])
        print("datePublished:", dictionary["result"]["sentences"][i]["volume"]["dateAdded"][:10])

parse_vocabulary_com_examples("abet")
```

returns:

```
    ------------------------------------------------------
    name: Scientific American
    sentence: This is aided and abetted both by partisan media sympathizers and by journalists who share misinformation live and correct it later.
    datePublished: 2020-03-25
    ------------------------------------------------------
    name: Fox News
    sentence: That dependence was the result of the CCP’s ruthless tactics, abetted by bad decisions by American policymakers and business people over many years.
    datePublished: 2020-03-25
    ------------------------------------------------------
    name: New York Times
    sentence: The Syrian government bet on and abetted such outcomes.
    datePublished: 2020-03-22
    ------------------------------------------------------
    name: Washington Post
    sentence: We must not aid and abet the CCP’s efforts to stoke internal divisions and spread disinformation.
    datePublished: 2020-03-20
```

Obviously you need to integrate it in your parser loop adding error controls (no result, for example no date available, or limited results, less than 4 or none). Also observe scraping policy ;)

In order to search all class occurrences:

```py
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

page4 = requests.get('https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/abet')
soup4 = BeautifulSoup(page4.content, 'html.parser')
examples = soup4.findAll(True, {'class': 'ex-sent first-child t no-aq sents'})

print("Number of elements found:", len(examples))
for i in examples:
    print("------------------------------------------------------")
    print(i.text.strip())
```

return:

```
Number of elements found: 3
----------------------------------------------
abet the commission of a crime
----------------------------------------------
The singer was abetted by a skillful accompanist.
----------------------------------------------
accused of aiding and abetting a criminal
```

You can try the following but it returns 26 matches, that is, the hidden results under the "See More" button. Note that the search for classes are now a list, it is a less restricted form and therefore it gets more results. Also, classes cannot contain spaces.

```py
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

page4 = requests.get('https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/abet')

soup4 = BeautifulSoup(page4.content, 'html.parser')
examples = soup4.findAll(True, {'class': ['ex-sent', 'first-child', 't', 'no-aq', 'sents']})

print("Number of elements found:", len(examples))
for i in examples:
    print("----------------------------------------------")
    print(i.text.strip())
```

Comment: how to parse the json response or selenium(uses of it), to call that sentences?

Comment: Thank u so much. And One more thing, how to call same name multiple classes to print?  i meant my last problem for when i call it from html .